# Namespace for using iTextSharp CSSResolver classes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp CSSResolver classes for using external css in vb.net

Please let me know the namespaces for using `XMLWorkerFontProvider`, `CssFilesImpl`, `StyleAttrCSSResolver` classes.

Below is my code:

```
    Dim fontProvider As XMLWorkerFontProvider = New XMLWorkerFontProvider()

    Dim cssFiles As CssFilesImpl = New CssFilesImpl(fontProvider)

    cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCSS())

    Dim cssRevolver As StyleAttrCSSResolver = New StyleAttrCSSResolver()

    Dim htmlContext As HtmlPipelineContext = New HtmlPipelineContext()

    htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory())

    htmlContext.SetImageProvider(New MyImageProvider(imagePath))

    Dim pipeline As IPipeline = New CssResolverPipeline(cssRevolver, New HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, New PdfWriterPipeline(Document, writer)))

    Dim worker As XMLWorker = New XMLWorker(pipeline, True)

    Dim p As XMLParser = New XMLParser(worker)

    p.Parse(xmlString)
```

Thanks
Ramesh

Dim sw As New StringWriter()

Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

strMonthlyDataHtml = LoadReport("PDF")

ltrPDFReport.Text = strMonthlyDataHtml

ltrPDFReport.RenderControl(hw)

Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())

Dim pdfDoc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)

Dim memStream = New MemoryStream()

Dim writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memStream)

writer.CloseStream = False

pdfDoc.Open()

Dim htmlContext As New HtmlPipelineContext(Nothing)

htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory())

Dim cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(False)

cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("../Assets/css/Efficiency.css"), True)

cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("/Assets/css/Efficiency.css"), True)

Dim pipeline As IPipeline = New CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, New
     HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, New PdfWriterPipeline(pdfDoc, writer)))

Dim worker As XMLWorker = New XMLWorker(pipeline, True)

Dim p As New XMLParser(worker)

p.Parse(sr)

pdfDoc.Close()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are mixing two different things. When I see `iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser`, I assume that you are using the old `HTMLWorker`, a class that has been discontinued.

When I look at your code, I see that you are using XML Worker, which requires a separate DLL ([itextsharp.xmlworker.dll](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/)). The classes you use are in `iTextSharp.tool.xml`, and have nothing to do with `iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser`. You can check this, by [downloading the ZIP file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/) and looking at the source code in `itextsharp-src-xmlworker.zip`.

Comment: Am I using the above correct code to make iTextSharp to apply the external CSS file ?

Comment: No, your code looks really strange. Where did you find it? Why are you doing it that way? What is your intention? I can't comment on your code, because I don't understand the purpose of your code.

Comment: I am trying to generate PDF using iTextSharp, but it is not applying external css file styles when included in xslt. so I am trying to take cssResolver of iText as edited in main section

Comment: I took the code from here                                                                               http://dotnetdatastuff.blogspot.in/2013/10/generate-pdf-using-html-file-and.html

Comment: I see plenty of differences between the code at the link and the code you share. I understand the code at the link your shared; I do not understand your code. Nor is the question you ask in the comment section clear. Your initial question was answered: you know which name space to use. Now create a new question if you have further doubts.