# The document has no pages exception while converting sharepoint page to pdf

Tags: c#, itext, sharepoint-2013

Using itextSharp and sharepoint visual webpart coding I am converting current aspx page to pdf but I am not to able convert. I have found that issue is in this line "this.Page.RenderControl(hw)" If I comment this line I get "The document has no pages" exception and If I uncomment this line I get "A page can have only one server-side Form tag" error. How can I handle this? Pls somebody help me pls..

```
protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 try
         {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 

            //this.Page.RenderControl(hw);

            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0.0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();


            }
        catch (Exception exp)
            {


            } 
 }

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // Ensure that the control is nested in a server form.
        if (Page != null)
        {
            Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(this);
        }
        base.Render(writer);
   }
```

Comment: You are using `HTMLWorker`. That class has been abandoned a long time because (1.) it was an ad hoc implementation of only a limited set of HTML tags, and (2.) the code was beyond repair. You should use iTextSharp's [XML Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker) instead. Chances are the `HTMLWorker` was not able to read your HTML and therefor produced no output (hence "The document has no pages"). Also: a PDF with 2 forms is impossible according to the specs. Form tags in HTML to PDF conversion are ignored.

Comment: I am using itextsharp 5.4.4 , in this XMLWorker class is not available. By the way while I use the above same code in asp.net works fine but while trying to use in sharepoint visual webpart its not working.

Comment: If you follow the link, you'll discover that XML Worker is an addon (another DLL) that is available under the same licence as iTextSharp. Please read the documentation before saying thing that aren't true. See also this recent question on StackOverflow:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212444/namespace-for-using-itextsharp-cssresolver-classes

Comment: Sorry for not reading the link properly, now I found the XML worker dll. I will learn how to use this dll for my work, then I will update this post.

Comment: Yes, but it is also important for us to understand what is different between the HTML produced by Sharepoint (that doesn't work) and the HTML that does work for you. I always find it awkward when people say that they are using iTextSharp to "convert aspx to PDF" because aspx isn't HTML. The **result** of an aspx page can be HTML, but the aspx file in itself isn't. It would help if you take away confusion by showing the HTML that you are trying to convert to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way ASP.NET web forms page lifecycle works (sharepoint very similar), you need to move the PDF generation code into the `Render` stage. IIRC that's why you see the "*A page can have only one server-side Form tag*" Exception - your `Page.RenderControl()` call in the button click event handler comes before the `Render()` stage, and basically results in rendering the page contents twice.

Anyway, here's a simple working example using `XMLWorker` to get you started:

first make sure to include these namespaces:

```
    using iTextSharp.text;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
    using iTextSharp.text.xml;
    using iTextSharp.tool.xml;
```

and then:

```
// flag when  page renders normally / when you're sending PDF
      private bool _convertToPdf;
// set _convertToPdf in your BtnSubmit_Click() - I never use AutoEventWireup
      public void ProcessPage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
          _convertToPdf = true;
      }

      protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        if (!_convertToPdf) { base.Render(writer); }
        else {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=thisPage.pdf");
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb)) {
                using (var htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)) {
                    base.Render(htmlTextWriter);
                    using (var document = new Document()) {
                        var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
                        document.Open();
                        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString())) {
                            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                                pdfWriter, document, stringReader
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Response.End();        
        }
```

Don't have high expectations regarding how well the PDF displays compared to your `aspx` page. iTextSharp isn't meant to be a full-blown HTML to PDF converter.

Comment: I am not getting any error during debugging and the pdf is getting generated but while I am  trying to open the generated pdf getting this error: Adobe reader could not open the ‘this.pdf’  because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged((‘for example it was sent as an email attachment and was not correctly docoded’)  I have replaced the Response as HttpContext.Current.Response as I am using from sharepoint 2013 visual webpart.

Comment: Replacing `Response` with `HttpContext.Current.Response` is definitely **not** the problem. The error opening the PDF is most likely a result of injecting the page's HTML source into the PDF. Open the PDF with a text editor to confirm. Did you use the example code as-is? Works for me.

Comment: When I open the generated pdf in notepad, I can see the data. I am using your same code only difference is I am executing the code from button click event. Can you confirm me did you test your code from asp.net or from sharepoint visual webpart?

Comment: No access to SharePoint, test run from asp.net. To clarify, though, you should **not** see any HTML in the PDF when opening in notepad. That will definitely cause the file damaged / corrupted error from Adobe Acrobat (reader).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following lines:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
printableArea.RenderControl(hw); // Here printable area is nothing but div on aspx page with id and runaat="server" tag.

StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
 string strHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
 sr.Close();
```